# Target _top from ASP.NET MVC Controller

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, post, iframe

An externally-hosted form populates an iframe of an ASP.NET MVC 2 website, and when the user submits the form they post back to an ActionResult on the host site.

This works great so far except the result page populates the iframe. Ideally the controller's ActionResult method could somehow target _top, and I have yet to find a way to do this.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's impossible. The `_top` targetting must be done on the client, before ever invoking the server:

```
<form target="_top" method="post" action="...">
    ...
</form>
```

Comment: That's what I figured; overly optimistic I guess. Thanks!